# Prove: If ab is a region in C, then ext ab is open.

Tags: general-topology

How do I go about proving this? I do not understand how I am supposed to show the openness of the exterior of a region.

May someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: How do you define the exterior of a region? That should be a good start...

Answer (score 0):

Start from the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_(topology)):

The union of any family of open sets is an open set.